# Multiple Linear Regression: a Significant Anova but NO significant coeffecient predictors?

Tags: statistics, regression, spss, anova

Multiple Linear Regression: a Significant ANOVA but NO significant coefficient predictors?

I have ran a multiple regression on 2 IVs to predict a dependant, all assumptions have been met, the ANOVA has a significant result but the coefficient table suggests that none of the predictors are significant?

what does this mean and how am I able to interpret the result of this?

(USED SPSS)

Answer (score 0):

This almost certainly means the two predictors are substantially correlated with each other. The REGRESSION procedure in SPSS Statistics has a variety of collinearity diagnostics to aid in detection of more complicated situations involving collinearity, but in this case simply correlating the two predictors should establish the basic point.